# How can I imlement a database trigger with java/JPA(EclipseLink)?

Tags: database, jpa, triggers, eclipselink

I have a few database triggers and I would like to implement them using JPA instead of using proprietary database triggers. 
Is this possible and how can I do this? I would appreciate example(s).

Comment: read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136042/triggers-versus-jpa-event)

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but this is not possible. some features are not available in JPA like triggers and views.

But it is possible to use @PreUpdate or @PrePersist (http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event) to modify data but imho they are quite tricky as the are executed by the JPA implementation. You should not rely on that data within your current action, as these lifecycle events are executed when your provider thinks it is the right moment.

Maybe it is possible to use a provider specific feature to implement triggers, but so you cannot switch your application server etc without finding another solution.