# JPA events instead of triggers on DB

Tags: hibernate, jpa, triggers

Is it possible to use JPA events, and eliminate complately triggers on DB? I need to make for example on PostPersist make update on different table.

Comment: Did you try or research interceptors? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_interceptors.htm

Comment: Possible, likely yes. Good idea, nope.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136042