# Refreshing entity after database trigger

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to update some fields of an entity and then return the updated entity. The corresponding table has a update trigger which sets the current timestamp in a column (I'd like to do this on a database level and not via JPA).

First I use the entitymanager's find() method to retrieve the existing entity via its ID and then update some fields using the entity's setters. However when I return the entity, the update column/field of my Java entity was not updated, even though it was updated in the database table through the update trigger.

I've tried the entitymanager's refresh() method after setting the changed values, but it seems that this voids all my changes (probably since the entity has not been committed yet?).

1) Is there a better way to get the correct values other than letting the transaction commit and then retrieve the entity again using find()?

2) I'm not really sure how to annotate the "last changed" column in my entity. What is the best way to annotate a field, that is only changed by a database trigger? Right now I'm using (since I only want the database trigger to update this field):

```
@Column(name = "last_changed", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Does anyone have some helpful input on this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Calling setters does not write anything to the database, and thus doesn't execute the trigger. What writes to the database is the flush() operation (which is called automatically before the commit, and also before executing some queries whose result depend on the pending changes). So you need to call flush(), then refresh(). That will obviously be slower and less efficient than ding it in Java, without a trigger

Comment: @JBNizet thank you, that's what I was looking for. I forgot that I could flush without committing first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Is there a better way to get the correct values other than letting
>   the transaction commit and then retrieve the entity again using
>   find()?

As @JBNizet commented: "So you need to call flush(), then refresh()."

> 2) I'm not really sure how to annotate the "last changed" column in my
>   entity. What is the best way to annotate a field, that is only changed
>   by a database trigger?

In addition to the @Column annotation with insertable and updateable set to false, one could use the hibernate annotation @Generated as shown [in this answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249785)
This however breaks any "JPA-only" approach.